# SetCellValue is not working for first row java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to write the data in excel file. When I am passing value to columns of first row (for heading), its value does not get updated but from row 2 onward I can see the data in excel file.
Below is the code I am using.

```
    public static void writeWorkBook(Map<String, List<String>> addressMap, List<String> userList) {
    System.out.println("Writing Process Started ");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    for (String user : userList) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data_" + user);
        int rownum = 1;
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("User");

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("Address");

        List<String> addressList = addressMap.get(user);
        for (String s : addressList) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(user);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(s);
        }
    }

    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://practice/java/testWrite.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("testWrite.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: All indexes are 0-based. So

```
...
int rownum = 1; 
Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
...
```

creates the **second** row. First row would be

```
...
int rownum = 0; 
Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
...
```

Second: In `row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);` at first the row is created and then `rownum` is incremented. So first row is created **again** instead of second row.

Do

```
...
row = sheet.createRow(++rownum);
...
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Getting and setting the rows are 0-based, so if you want to have the description in the first row, you need use 0 as argument in

```
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
```